# Entity framework 6.1: 1-1 and 1-many relationship in derived types and identifying relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6.1, ef-fluent-api

**Update:** I should have noted that the `Id` property on `NavigationPropertyClass` is not database generated. In my actual model, `NavigationPropertyClass` is also part of a hierarchy scheme (using TPH) which is not shown here , and while `NavigationPropertyClass` has a `DerivedClass1` instance and a collection of `DerivedClass2` instances, this is not necessarily the case with all classes that inherit from the base class from which `NavigationPropertyClass` is derived.

---

A portion of my model looks something like this (other properties and constructors omitted for brevity):

```
//Many other classes inherit from this class
//and many of the derived classes are not composed of DerivedClass1 or DerivedClass2
public abstract SomeOtherBaseClass{
    public int Id {get; set;} //not database generated, set in the constructor
}

public NavigationPropertyClass: SomeOtherBaseClass{
    public DerivedClass1 Derived1 {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<DerivedClass2> Derived2Collection {get; set;}
}

public abstract class BaseClass{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    //other properties shared by derived classes
}

public class DerivedClass1: BaseClass{
    public NavigationPropertyClass NavigationProperty {get; set;}
    //other properties pertinent to DerivedClass1
}


public class DerivedClass2: BaseClass{
    public NavigationPropertyClass NavigationProperty {get; set;}
    //other properties pertinent to DerivedClass2
}
```

`DerivedClass1` has a 1-1 relationship with `NavigationPropertyClass`, while `DerivedClass2` has a many-1 relationship with `NavigationPropertyClass`.

I'm trying to set up identifying relationships in each of the derived classes so that when the instance of `NavigationPropertyClass` is deleted from the database, so too will the associated instance of `DerivedClass1` and any instances of `DerivedClass2`. The only way I can see to set this up is with TPT inheritance, but even so, I cannot get things working correctly. I'd post my Fluent API configuration, but I've tried so many permutations at this point that I wouldn't know which one to post.

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to do? If so, what does the Fluent API config look like?

Comment: _while Derived2 has a 1-many relationship with NavigationPropertyClass_ => One Derived2 has many NavigationPropertyClass ?

Comment: @YuliamChandra edited to correctly identify the direction of the relationship.

Comment: EF doesn't have to know `Base`, you can map the derived classes as independent entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the models that fit your requirement.

```
public abstract class Base
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
public class Derived1 : Base
{
    public int PropDerived1 { get; set; }
    public NavigationPropertyClass NavigationProperty { get; set; }
}
public class Derived2 : Base
{
    public int PropDerived2 { get; set; }

    public int NavigationPropertyClassId { get; set; }
    public NavigationPropertyClass NavigationPropertyClass { get; set; }
}
public abstract class SomeOtherBaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
public class NavigationPropertyClass : SomeOtherBaseClass
{
    public Derived1 Derived1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Derived2> Derived2s { get; set; }
}
```

And you only need to use `ToTable` to have TPT inheritance when configuring the model builder.

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SomeOtherBaseClass> SomeOtherBaseClasses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Base> Bases { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Derived1>().ToTable("Derived1");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Derived2>().ToTable("Derived2");
        modelBuilder.Entity<NavigationPropertyClass>().ToTable("NavigationPropertyClass");

        modelBuilder.Entity<NavigationPropertyClass>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.Derived1)
            .WithRequiredDependent(x => x.NavigationProperty);
    }
}
```

And leave everything to [EF convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx), except the part where `NavigationPropertyClass::Id` is also an FK to `Derived1`.

Result

[image: Result]

Simplified generated constraint on `NavigationPropertyClass` table:

```
PRIMARY KEY [Id]
FOREIGN KEY([Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Derived1] ([Id])
FOREIGN KEY([Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[SomeOtherBaseClasses] ([Id])
```

More

- [Mapping the Table-Per-Type (TPT) Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#2.5)

Comment: It looks like I may have oversimplified my model, as the Id on NavigationPropertyClass is not an identity column and as such NavigationPropertyClass is the principal end of the relationship. I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: @joelmdev, I updated the answer based on your updated question